# Puppet: Error: Could not set 'file' on ensure: getaddrinfo: Name or service not known on Ubuntu 14.04 x64

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system, puppet, ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying to use Puppet to deploy a server on Ubuntu 14.04 x64.

I can ping the puppet server fine, and the server is set correctly in puppet.conf. Puppet can connect to the master, send its key, I can sign the key on the master and begin to run the deployment without any problems, however when running the deployment I see the following errors:

```
Error: Could not set 'file' on ensure: getaddrinfo: Name or service not known
Error: Could not set 'file' on ensure: getaddrinfo: Name or service not known
Wrapped exception:
getaddrinfo: Name or service not known
Error: /File[/var/lib/puppet/lib/puppet/provider/a2mod.rb]/ensure: change from absent to file failed: Could not set 'file' on ensure: getaddrinfo: Name or service not known
```

I receive this multiple times (full output here: http://pastebin.com/mx6eXGvd).

All of my files in the puppet manifest use the `puppet:///modules/MODULE/FILE` format, and I've never had any problems like this before. It's clear that the puppet agent and master can communicate, so does anybody know what would be causing this error?

Comment: Try running puppet with `--debug`; that gives a lot more info and, if you're lucky, a full stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

Also from your output is this line:
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: getaddrinfo: Name or service not known

This makes me think that your DNS resolution on your puppet agent is broken, and your client is unable to find a server named 'puppet' (or whatever hostname you've set as 'server' in puppet.conf).

Comment: I though this too, but if this was the case why could it contact the Puppet server in the first place? In the end, the problem just resolved itself with no real input from me.